# Using spring batch without maven dependencies

Tags: spring-batch

Actually my entire application was  in dynamic web application using struts approach.I want to do batch processing operations using spring batch.Is it possible to use spring batch without using maven in my application.?

Comment: Maven is just a convenient way to build applications which have a lot of dependencies (and even more than that). So you can do it without Maven, but I'll be much trickier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use spring batch without using maven in my application.?

Yes. You need to download Spring Batch jars with their dependencies (along with their transitive dependencies) and add them to your classpath.